# Yeoman and angular - routing doesn't work

Tags: javascript, angularjs, yeoman

I'm trying start developing angular apps with yeoman. It may sounds stupid, but I have a problem with creating routes using yo:angular route.

When I create new route using:

```
yo:angular route foo
```

yeoman creates:

```
app/scripts/controllers/foo.js              (controller)
app/views/foo.html                          (view)
app/test/spec/controllers/foo.js            (testing the controller)
```

in app.js it creates:

```
  .config(function ($routeProvider) {
   $routeProvider
  .when('/', {
    templateUrl: 'views/main.html',
    controller: 'MainCtrl'
  })
  .when('/foo', {
    templateUrl: 'views/foo.html',
    controller: 'FooCtrl'
  })
  .otherwise({
    redirectTo: '/'
  });
});
```

so everything should work fine. Unfortunately the route doesn't work - when I try open

```
http://localhost:9000/foo
```

I get following error:

```
Cannot GET /foo
```

The idea of routes in yeoman looks pretty easy and I'm not sure where the problem is.

Comment: how do you serve your app? node/apache/nginx/..? try to make a link to `/foo` on the home page and access it from the home page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you enable HTML5 mode in your Angular application? If not, the URL would be:

```
http://localhost:9000/#/foo
```

And if you have enabled HTML5 mode in your Angular application, you have to make sure whatever server you're using has been configured to handle all routes as they were the root of the application.